# Cannot add/remove/toggle element class inside Vue directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This works: https://jsfiddle.net/hxyv40ra

However, when I place this code inside of a vue directive the button event is triggered and the console shows the class is removed **but** nothing visually changes?

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/hLga2jxq

Directive code is also below (to appease stackoverflow's rules).

**styles**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-hide-for="'uniqueID'">toggle to show?</button>
  <div class="hide" hide-name="uniqueID">
    Hello! :D
  </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
Vue.directive('hide-for', {
    bind(button, b, vnode, oldVnode) {
        console.log(b);
        var elsToToggle = document.querySelectorAll(`[hide-name="${b.value}"]`);
        console.log(button, b.value, `[hide-name="${b.value}"]`, elsToToggle);

        button.addEventListener('click', (b) => {
            console.log(button, " clicked");
            elsToToggle.forEach((el) => {
                console.log(el);
                el.classList.toggle('hide');
            })
        }, false)
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
  name: "test",
  el: '#app',
  data: {}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried this from another angle and also made the 'hide-name' attribute a directive as well, then on click I emitted the 'uniqueID' which 'hide-name' directive picked up.

*I'm still not sure why Vue is not visually updating the browser but I'm guessing it must have something to do with the 'virtual-dom'.*

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hLga2jxq/3/

```
Vue.directive('hide-for', {
    bind(el, b, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener('click', (event) => vnode.context.$emit(b.value, event) );
    }
});

Vue.directive('hide-name', {
    bind(el, b, vnode, oldVnode) {
        vnode.context.$on(b.value, function(){
            let hasHideClassAttr = el.getAttribute('hide-class');
            if(hasHideClassAttr) hasHideClassAttr.split(' ').forEach((c) => el.classList.toggle(c) );
            else el.classList.toggle('hide');
        });
    }
});
```